# How can i prevent a user from entering only numbers in an input field

Tags: html, angular

I should be able to enter alpha numeric values or just alphabets.
i need pattern for validation in angular 4

Comment: [Regex pattern ?](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

Comment: @Hearner there's faster.

Comment: '/[a-zA-Z]/' for the initial question, `^\w+$` for the current question

Comment: @Adder same, there's faster ways.

Comment: @trichetriche Did you notice he changed the question?

Comment: I don't see any edit on his post, and I stand by my statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `isNaN(input.value)`.

If it returns true, you're good. If not, it's only numbers.

Comment: What about `isNaN(".0")`?

Comment: That's a number.

Comment: But it isn't only numbers.

Comment: It isn't only **figures**, but it indeed is a number.

Comment: And your answer relates to the question how?

Comment: The user can't input only numbers in the field, and he can enter alphanumeric values or just characters. Which is **exactly** what is asked there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom `attribute directive` for prevent alphabets.

I have create a demo on [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/postal-code-input-with-only-numberslimited-5--l-angular-45?file=src%2Fapp%2Fonly-number.directive.ts)

> components.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" OnlyNumber placeholder="Enter postal code" formControlName="postalCode" />
  <p>{{myForm.get('postalCode').value}}</p>
</form>
```

> components.ts

```
myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      postalCode: [null, Validators.required]
    });
}
```

> only-number.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[OnlyNumber]'
})
export class OnlyNumberDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
        /* 
            8 -  for backspace
            9 -  for tab
            13 - for enter
            27 - for escape
            46 - for delete
        */
        if ([8, 9, 13, 27, 46].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+C
            (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+V
            (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+X
            (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
            // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
            return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        this.validateFields(event);
    }
    validateFields(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let numberRegEx = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if(!numberRegEx.test(this.el.nativeElement.value)){
                this.el.nativeElement.value = "";
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }, 100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use *HTML* only, you can set type in input like this:

```
<input type="number" />
```

But you can use **regular expression** in *javascript* like this:
`'/[a-zA-Z]/'` 
or ...

Comment: He is asking for the opposite.